# Skype for Business Server on Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine, skype-for-business

We are planning to integrate Skype Video conferencing into our web application. We are not using `Azure AD` at the moment so `SfB Online` is not an option. So we are thinking of setting up `Skype for Business Server` on Azure VM.

Questions :

1. Is it possible to setup `SfB server` on `Azure VM`. I read in some posts that it is not supported by Microsoft . [Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2721672/microsoft-server-software-support-for-microsoft-azure-virtual-machines) and [Link2](https://insidemstech.com/2016/10/18/skype4b-key-planning-considerations-for-sfb-on-azure-iaas-part-iii/)?
2. Is `Azure AD` the only authentication option for `SfB Server` ?
3. Any samples or guidance on how to proceed on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a SFB Server on azure for the sake of using current protocols in my opinion outweighs the disadvantages of learning how to use Azure AD in your webapp... It is really easy to learn.  I would recommend that you take the SFB online approach and really consider it.  THere will be overhead that you will have with the SFB in Azure VM approach like patching, etc.

However, if you really need to go down this road (Good luck btw...), here's my thoughts.

1. Correct, it's not supported, because you cannot guarantee the performance you will get out the server.  Normally SFB on a VM even on prem needs to use reserved resources.  Something we cannot do in Azure at this point.  Technically, it will install, it will work, but if things go sideways, don't expect to get support.
2. SFB Server..... no... You can use a DC in Azure IaaS, or, you could look at ADDS (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-ds/).  SFB Online, you will be interfacing with the web api... not 100% sure, but I think you will be passing in Azure AD (check https://ucwa.skype.com/)